# Mapping nested objects from root node is not working

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

Using **ObjectMapper**(https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), I'm doing `JSON` conversion to `Swift` Objects. App is crashing while accessing `user.profession`.

Basically, I do not know how to parse another mappable object inside the model with same JSON map root node I think, I'm doing it wrong. I can't find the documentation for the same anywhere.

**JSON dictionary:**

```
user: {
  "name": "Dinesh",
  "url": "https://dinaraja.me",
  "company": "IIINC",
  "designation": "Developer"
}
```

**Model:**

```
struct User: Mappable {
  var name: String!
  var url: URL!
  var profession: Profession!
  init(_ map: Map) {
    name <- map["name"]
    url <- map["url"]
    profession <- map   // FIXME: It's not working. Find out what we do here is right/wrong
  }
}
struct Profession: Mappable {
  var company: String!
  var designation: String!
  init(_ map: Map) {
    company <- map["company"]
    designation <- map["designation"]
  }
}
```

**What I did:**

```
let user = Mapper<User>().map(myJSONDictionary)
print(user.profession.company) //FIXME: Crashes here
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since `profession` model its not included directly in `user` json model you should not use object mapper `<-` operator in this case. Instead you should initialize new `Profession` object directly from `user` mapping function

```
struct User: Mappable {
    var name: String!
    var url: URL!
    var profession: Profession!

    init(map: Map) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        name <- map["name"]
        url <- map["url"]
        profession = Profession(map: map)
    }
}

struct Profession: Mappable {
    var company: String!
    var designation: String!

    init(map: Map) {
        company <- map["company"]
        designation <- map["designation"]
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        company <- map["company"]
        designation <- map["designation"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But, it calls the `init(map: Map)` and not calling `func mapping(map:)` at all. I'm actually mapping explicitly now. :(

`profession = Mapper<Profession>(context: map.context, shouldIncludeNilValues: false).map(JSON: map.JSON)`